# Tikz callout: positioning start of pointer

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, shapes

The pointers of my Tikz callout rectangles always start in the middle of the rectangle. But that kind of pointer sometimes gets in the way of other objects (e.g. the pointer start should be more to the left in the example below).

Thus I want to **position the start of the pointer** manually, e.g. via degree or `.south west` or the like. (How) can I do that? Can I somehow modify the standard tikz callout such that this positioning can be determined by some parameter? Or is there an alternative package for this?

---

Here is a minimal working example (mwe):

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
\node[draw, align=center, rounded corners=2pt, rectangle] at (2.6,-1.7) (c22) {Further Rectangle};

\node[rectangle callout,draw,inner sep=2pt,color=red,
   callout absolute pointer={(c22.west)}] at (1.48,-.95) {no
     workarounds; no exceptions to optimizations}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The mwe results in the first figure, but I would like sth. like the second figure.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: well, you need to read manual for TikZ. There are some examples from which you can se, what to do. For desired position and form of your callout you do the following: (i) line with "above right= 5pt and -11pt of c22.north west" replace with "above right= 5pt and -0pt of c22.north east" and (ii) omit backslashes in text ...

Comment: There is no solution via callouts. Extract from pgfmanual: "The position on the border of the main shape to which the pointer is connected is
determined automatically."

Comment: Thanks a lot Paul, I missed that :( Is there an alternative? (I extended the questions in my OP according to this fact.)

Answer (score 6):

pointer of callout shape lies on line, which go through given coordinate (in your case c22.west) and center of callout shape. in your case you determined callout position regarding its shape center.

i'm afreid, that i not understand well what you like to achieve, so below is mwe, which show, how will me design your sketch:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
\node[draw, align=center, rounded corners=2pt,
      rectangle] at (2.6,-1.7) (c22) {Further Rectangle};

\node[rectangle callout,draw,inner sep=2pt,color=red,align=left,
      callout absolute pointer=(c22.west),
      above left= 5pt and 0pt of c22.north west]
      {no workarounds;  \\
       no exceptions    \\
       to optimizations};

\node[draw, align=center, rounded corners=2pt,
      rectangle] at (2.6,-3.7) (d22) {Further Rectangle};

\node[rectangle callout,draw,inner sep=2pt,color=red,align=left,
      callout absolute pointer=(d22.west),
      above left= 5pt and 0pt of d22.north east]
      {no workarounds;  no exceptions  to optimizations};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

in example i use library positioning, which gives freedom in callout shape placing. if you insist, that text in callout is one line, just omit backslashes in text. for moving call out more to left (that pointer will not cross tha shape) just determine new position of callout shape similar as i do for second case

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer, Zarko. I've added a picture to my original post of what I mean by "position the start of the pointer".

Comment: as my picture shows, I do not want to move the rectangles around, only the callout pointer (the triangle part) while keeping the rectangles position fixed.

Comment: As mentioned in the answer, the pointer's direction is determined by connecting the pointer and the **center** anchor of the shape (the red rectangle in this case); this is hardcoded in the shape library and cannot be controlled via keys. You can always request this feature to be added to tikz but at present the only option is to define your own shape that does that, or to draw the callout yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Although this question is quite old it seems like there’s is no official way to do it yet. I took a look at the original definition and found a way to move the starting point around: I introduce the two new options

```
callout pointer xshift = <dim>
callout pointer yshift = <dim>
```

which can be used to shift the point where the pointer starts by `<dim>`. It can be used with the existing `rectangle callout` shape, like this:

```
\node at (2,3) [
   draw,
   rectangle callout,
   callout absolute pointer = (A.north),
   callout pointer xshift = -20mm,
] {This is a long callout with a pointer \textbf{not} starting from the middle};
```

The upper part of the image shows the callouts with original pointer starting points and the lower parts shows the shifted ones.

[image]

This requires to add the lines

```
\advance\pgf@x\callout@move@pointer@start@x
```

and

```
\advance\pgf@y\callout@move@pointer@start@y
```

in the definition of `\pgf@lib@rectanglecallout@pointer`, where the two points `\beforecalloutpointer` and `\aftercalloutpointer` are calculated. These lines just add the `<dim>` set with the new key options to the originally calculated coordinates.

**Full code**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{parskip}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.callouts}

\makeatletter

\newlength{\callout@move@pointer@start@x}
\newlength{\callout@move@pointer@start@y}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/.cd,
    callout pointer xshift/.code={\setlength{\callout@move@pointer@start@x}{#1}},
    callout pointer yshift/.code={\setlength{\callout@move@pointer@start@y}{#1}},
}

% \pgf@lib@rectanglecallout@pointer
%
% Internal macro for calculations relating to the rectangle callout.
%
% Requires the following to be set up:
%
% \calloutpointer - the location of the callout point.
% \xtemp          - the half width of the rectangle
% \ytemp          - the half height of the rectangle
% \pointerwidth   - the width of the pointer.
%
\def\pgf@lib@rectanglecallout@pointer{%
    %
    % Ensure that the pointer never connects to the main shape
    % too near to a corner. This is done for two reasons:
    % 1. It can look ugly.
    % 2. If the corners are rounded, a mess can result.
    %
    \pgfextract@process\borderpoint{%
            \pgfpointborderrectangle{%
                \centerpoint%
                \pgf@xa\pgf@x%
                \pgf@ya\pgf@y%
                \calloutpointer%
                \advance\pgf@x-\pgf@xa%
                \advance\pgf@y-\pgf@ya%
            }{\pgfqpoint{\xtemp}{\ytemp}}%
        }%
    \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\pgfpointorigin}{\borderpoint}%
    \let\borderangle\pgfmathresult%
    %
    \pgfutil@tempdima\pointerwidth\relax%
    \pgf@xa\xtemp\relax%
    \advance\pgf@xa-\pgfutil@tempdima%
    \pgf@ya\ytemp\relax%
    \advance\pgf@ya-\pgfutil@tempdima%
    %
    \pgf@process{%
        \pgfutil@ifundefined{pgf@corner@arc}{\pgfpointorigin}{%
            \expandafter\pgfqpoint\pgf@corner@arc}%
    }%
    \advance\pgf@xa-\pgf@x%
    \advance\pgf@ya-\pgf@y%
    %
    \borderpoint%
    \pgf@xb\pgf@x%
    \pgf@yb\pgf@y%
    %
    \pgf@xc0pt\relax%
    \pgf@yc0pt\relax%
    %
    \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfqpoint{\xtemp}{\ytemp}}%
    \ifdim\borderangle pt<\pgfmathresult pt\relax%
        \pgf@yc.5\pgfutil@tempdima%
        \ifdim\pgf@yb>\pgf@ya%
            \pgf@yb\pgf@ya%
        \fi%
        %
        % Establish the order for drawing the rectangle corners.
        %
        \edef\firstpoint{\noexpand\pgfqpoint{\xtemp}{\ytemp}}%
        \edef\secondpoint{\noexpand\pgfqpoint{-\xtemp}{\ytemp}}%
        \edef\thirdpoint{\noexpand\pgfqpoint{-\xtemp}{-\ytemp}}%
        \edef\fourthpoint{\noexpand\pgfqpoint{\xtemp}{-\ytemp}}%
    \else%
        \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfqpoint{-\xtemp}{\ytemp}}%
        \ifdim\borderangle pt<\pgfmathresult pt\relax%
            \pgf@xc-.5\pgfutil@tempdima%
            \ifdim\pgf@xb>\pgf@xa%
                \pgf@xb\pgf@xa%
            \else%
                \ifdim\pgf@xb<-\pgf@xa%
                    \pgf@xb-\pgf@xa%
                \fi%
            \fi%
            \edef\firstpoint{\noexpand\pgfqpoint{-\xtemp}{\ytemp}}%
            \edef\secondpoint{\noexpand\pgfqpoint{-\xtemp}{-\ytemp}}%
            \edef\thirdpoint{\noexpand\pgfqpoint{\xtemp}{-\ytemp}}%
            \edef\fourthpoint{\noexpand\pgfqpoint{\xtemp}{\ytemp}}%
        \else%
            \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfqpoint{-\xtemp}{-\ytemp}}%
            \ifdim\borderangle pt<\pgfmathresult pt\relax%
                \pgf@yc-.5\pgfutil@tempdima%
                \ifdim\pgf@yb>\pgf@ya%
                    \pgf@yb\pgf@ya%
                \else%
                    \ifdim\pgf@yb<-\pgf@ya%
                        \pgf@yb-\pgf@ya%
                    \fi%
                \fi%
                \edef\firstpoint{\noexpand\pgfqpoint{-\xtemp}{-\ytemp}}%
                \edef\secondpoint{\noexpand\pgfqpoint{\xtemp}{-\ytemp}}%
                \edef\thirdpoint{\noexpand\pgfqpoint{\xtemp}{\ytemp}}%
                \edef\fourthpoint{\noexpand\pgfqpoint{-\xtemp}{\ytemp}}%
            \else%
                \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfqpoint{\xtemp}{-\ytemp}}%
                \ifdim\borderangle pt<\pgfmathresult pt\relax%
                    \pgf@xc.5\pgfutil@tempdima%
                    \ifdim\pgf@xb>\pgf@xa%
                        \pgf@xb\pgf@xa%
                    \else%
                        \ifdim\pgf@xb<-\pgf@xa%
                            \pgf@xb-\pgf@xa%
                        \fi%
                    \fi%
                    \edef\firstpoint{\noexpand\pgfqpoint{\xtemp}{-\ytemp}}%
                    \edef\secondpoint{\noexpand\pgfqpoint{\xtemp}{\ytemp}}%
                    \edef\thirdpoint{\noexpand\pgfqpoint{-\xtemp}{\ytemp}}%
                    \edef\fourthpoint{\noexpand\pgfqpoint{-\xtemp}{-\ytemp}}%
                \else%
                    \pgf@yc.5\pgfutil@tempdima%
                    \ifdim\pgf@yb<-\pgf@ya%
                        \pgf@yb-\pgf@ya%
                    \fi%
                    \edef\firstpoint{\noexpand\pgfqpoint{\xtemp}{\ytemp}}%
                    \edef\secondpoint{\noexpand\pgfqpoint{-\xtemp}{\ytemp}}%
                    \edef\thirdpoint{\noexpand\pgfqpoint{-\xtemp}{-\ytemp}}%
                    \edef\fourthpoint{\noexpand\pgfqpoint{\xtemp}{-\ytemp}}%
                \fi%
            \fi%
        \fi%
    \fi%
    \pgfextract@process\beforecalloutpointer{%
        \centerpoint%
        \advance\pgf@x\pgf@xb%
        \advance\pgf@x\callout@move@pointer@start@x% <------------------ ADDED HERE
        \advance\pgf@y\pgf@yb%
        \advance\pgf@y\callout@move@pointer@start@y% <------------------ ADDED HERE
        \advance\pgf@x-\pgf@xc%     
        \advance\pgf@y-\pgf@yc%
    }%  
    \pgfextract@process\aftercalloutpointer{%
        \centerpoint%
        \advance\pgf@x\pgf@xb%
        \advance\pgf@x\callout@move@pointer@start@x% <------------------ ADDED HERE
        \advance\pgf@y\pgf@yb%
        \advance\pgf@y\callout@move@pointer@start@y% <------------------ ADDED HERE
        \advance\pgf@x\pgf@xc%      
        \advance\pgf@y\pgf@yc%
    }%  
    %
    % Now calculate the pointer anchor.
    %
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@x{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep}}%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@y{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer ysep}}%
    \ifdim\pgf@x>\pgf@y%
        \edef\outersep{\the\pgf@x}%
    \else%
        \edef\outersep{\the\pgf@y}%
    \fi%
    \pgf@lib@callouts@pointeranchor%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
   \node [fill, gray,circle] (A) at (2,1) {};
   \node at (2,3) [
      draw,
      rectangle callout,
      callout absolute pointer = (A.north),
   ] {This is a long callout with a pointer starting from the middle};
   \node at (5,1) [
      draw,
      rectangle callout,
      callout absolute pointer = (A.east),
      text width = 40mm,
   ] {This is a long callout with a pointer starting from the middle};
\end{tikzpicture}

\bigskip
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \node [fill, gray,circle] (A) at (2,1) {};
   \node at (2,3) [
      draw,
      rectangle callout,
      callout absolute pointer = (A.north),
      callout pointer xshift = -20mm,
   ] {This is a long callout with a pointer \textbf{not} starting from the middle};
   \node at (5,1) [
      draw,
      rectangle callout,
      callout absolute pointer = (A.east),
      callout pointer yshift = 4mm,
      text width = 40mm,
   ] {This is a long callout with a pointer \textbf{not} starting from the middle};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: could you please extend your solution to support absolute positioning of the pointer on the shape border like ```callout pointer anchor = south``` at least for the four border anchors east, north, west, south? I have a set of callouts and it looks much better when their callout pointers start at the same position of the borders. Your help is much appreciated. Thank you