# TikZ callouts: How to prevent sharp pointer tip from being rounded?

Tags: tikz-pgf, callout

When drawing a corner-rounded callout box, the pointer tip is rounded as well.

Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.callouts}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node [anchor=south west] at (0, 0) (cartoon) {\includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth,height=.15\textwidth]{example-image-a}};
        \node [anchor=north west,rectangle callout,draw=black,
        callout absolute pointer=(cartoon.east), 
        rounded corners=3pt,text width=0.7\textwidth, inner sep=2ex] at (.19\textwidth,.125\textwidth) {This is an example.};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: The result]

What I want is something like this:

[image: Expected result]

If `rounded corners=3pt` is off, the pointer tip would always be sharp.

So I guess the option is the cause.

But while moving the pointer position farther away, like `callout absolute pointer=(cartoon.west)`, the pointer tip was sharp back (more exactly, it is still rounded, but hardly being visibly dectected).

I looked up the TikZ manual and found little controlling the pointer shape besides the pointer width.

Is there any easy way to control this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The boundary path is defined in the node shape. So you can define your own node shape based on the `rectangle callout`, in which you make the corner at the tip sharp. Since the original callout already has two corners that are always sharp, you only need to repeat what is already done by adding one more `\pgfsetcornersarced{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}` in a local group. I marked the additional lines by `<-`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.callouts}
\makeatletter
\pgfdeclareshape{sharp rectangle callout}{%
    \savedmacro\rectanglecalloutpoints{%
        %
        \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@x{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep}}%
        \advance\pgf@x.5\wd\pgfnodeparttextbox%
        \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@xa{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/minimum width}}%
        \ifdim\pgf@x<.5\pgf@xa%
            \pgf@x.5\pgf@xa%
        \fi%
        \edef\xtemp{\the\pgf@x}%
        \pgfmathaddtolength\pgf@x{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep}}%
        %
        \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@y{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner ysep}}%
        \advance\pgf@y.5\ht\pgfnodeparttextbox%
        \advance\pgf@y.5\dp\pgfnodeparttextbox%
        \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@ya{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/minimum height}}%
        \ifdim\pgf@y<.5\pgf@ya%
            \pgf@y.5\pgf@ya%
        \fi%
        \edef\ytemp{\the\pgf@y}%
        \pgfmathaddtolength\pgf@y{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer ysep}}%
        %
        \edef\xlength{\the\pgf@x}%
        \edef\ylength{\the\pgf@y}%
        \addtosavedmacro\xlength%
        \addtosavedmacro\ylength%
        %
        \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\pointerwidth{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/callout pointer width}}%
        \addtosavedmacro\pointerwidth%
        %
        \pgfextract@process\centerpoint{%
            \pgf@x.5\wd\pgfnodeparttextbox%
            \pgf@y.5\ht\pgfnodeparttextbox%
            \advance\pgf@y-.5\dp\pgfnodeparttextbox%
        }%
        %
        % Process the relative callout pointer.
        %
        \ifpgf@lib@callout@absolutepointer%
        \else%
            \pgfextract@process\calloutpointer{%
                \pgfextract@process\borderpoint{%
                    \expandafter\pgfpointborderrectangle\expandafter{\pgf@lib@callout@relativepointer}%
                        {\pgfqpoint{\xtemp}{\ytemp}}%
                }%
                \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\pgfpointorigin}{\borderpoint}%
                \let\pointerangle\pgfmathresult%
                \expandafter\pgf@process\expandafter{\pgf@lib@callout@relativepointer}%
                \pgfmathveclen@{\pgfmath@tonumber{\pgf@x}}{\pgfmath@tonumber{\pgf@y}}%
                \edef\pointerradius{\pgfmathresult pt}%
                \pgfpointadd{\borderpoint}{\pgfqpointpolar{\pointerangle}{\pointerradius}}%
                \pgf@xa\pgf@x%
                \pgf@ya\pgf@y%
                \centerpoint%
                \advance\pgf@x\pgf@xa%
                \advance\pgf@y\pgf@ya%
            }%
            \pgf@lib@callouts@shortenpointer%
            \addtosavedmacro\calloutpointer%
            \pgf@lib@rectanglecallout@pointer%
            \addtosavedmacro\calloutpointeranchor%
            \addtosavedmacro\beforecalloutpointer%
            \addtosavedmacro\aftercalloutpointer%
            \addtosavedmacro\firstpoint%
            \addtosavedmacro\secondpoint%
            \addtosavedmacro\thirdpoint%
            \addtosavedmacro\fourthpoint%
        \fi%
    }%
    \savedanchor\centerpoint{%
        \pgf@x.5\wd\pgfnodeparttextbox%
        \pgf@y.5\ht\pgfnodeparttextbox%
        \advance\pgf@y-.5\dp\pgfnodeparttextbox%
    }%
    \savedanchor\basepoint{%
        \pgf@x.5\wd\pgfnodeparttextbox%
        \pgf@y0pt\relax%
    }%
    \savedanchor\midpoint{%
        \pgf@x.5\wd\pgfnodeparttextbox%
        \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@y{+.5em}%
    }%
    \anchor{center}{\centerpoint}%
    \anchor{mid}{\midpoint}%
    \anchor{mid east}{%
        \rectanglecalloutpoints%
        \midpoint%
        \advance\pgf@x\xlength\relax%
    }%
    \anchor{mid west}{%
        \rectanglecalloutpoints%
        \midpoint%
        \advance\pgf@x-\xlength\relax%
    }%
    \anchor{base}{\basepoint}%
    \anchor{base east}{%
        \rectanglecalloutpoints%
        \basepoint%
        \advance\pgf@x\xlength\relax%
    }%
    \anchor{base west}{%
        \rectanglecalloutpoints%
        \basepoint%
        \advance\pgf@x-\xlength\relax%
    }%
    \anchor{north}{%
        \rectanglecalloutpoints%
        \centerpoint%
        \advance\pgf@y\ylength\relax%
    }%
    \anchor{south}{%
        \rectanglecalloutpoints%
        \centerpoint%
        \advance\pgf@y-\ylength\relax%
    }%
    \anchor{east}{%
        \rectanglecalloutpoints%
        \centerpoint%
        \advance\pgf@x\xlength\relax%
    }%
    \anchor{west}{%
        \rectanglecalloutpoints%
        \centerpoint%
        \advance\pgf@x-\xlength\relax%
    }%
    \anchor{north east}{%
        \rectanglecalloutpoints%
        \centerpoint%
        \advance\pgf@x\xlength\relax%
        \advance\pgf@y\ylength\relax%
    }%
    \anchor{south west}{%
        \rectanglecalloutpoints%
        \centerpoint%
        \advance\pgf@x-\xlength\relax%
        \advance\pgf@y-\ylength\relax%
    }%
    \anchor{south east}{%
        \rectanglecalloutpoints%
        \centerpoint%
        \advance\pgf@x\xlength\relax%
        \advance\pgf@y-\ylength\relax%
    }%
    \anchor{north west}{%
        \rectanglecalloutpoints%
        \centerpoint%
        \advance\pgf@x-\xlength\relax%
        \advance\pgf@y\ylength\relax%
    }%
    \anchor{pointer}{%
        \rectanglecalloutpoints%
        \calloutpointeranchor%
    }%
    \backgroundpath{%
        \rectanglecalloutpoints%
        \pgf@x\xlength\relax%
        \pgf@y\ylength\relax%
        \pgfmathaddtolength\pgf@x{-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep}}%
        \pgfmathaddtolength\pgf@y{-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer ysep}}%
        \edef\xtemp{\the\pgf@x}%
        \edef\ytemp{\the\pgf@y}%
        %
        % The absolute pointer must be calculated here because the
        % anchor of the shape (which is calculated after the saved
        % macros and points) affects how the pointer joins the
        % main rectangle.
        %
        \ifpgf@lib@callout@absolutepointer%
            \pgfextract@process\calloutpointer{%
                \pgfpointanchor{pgf@lib@callout@pointer}{center}%
            }%
            \pgf@lib@callouts@shortenpointer%
            \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\pointerwidth{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/callout pointer width}}%
            \pgf@lib@rectanglecallout@pointer%
            %
            % \pgf@node@name = the shape name (from \pgfmultipartnode)
            %
            \ifx\pgf@node@name\pgfutil@empty%
            \else%
                %
                % Now hack an extra saved anchor \calloutpointeranchor,
                % with the new anchor for the callout pointer.
                %
                \edef\pgf@sh@@temp{\noexpand\expandafter\noexpand\pgfutil@g@addto@macro\noexpand\csname pgf@sh@np@\pgf@node@name\noexpand\endcsname}%
                \edef\pgf@sh@@@temp{%
                    \noexpand\def\noexpand\calloutpointeranchor{%
                        \noexpand\pgf@x\the\pgf@x%
                        \noexpand\pgf@y\the\pgf@y%
                    }%
                }%
                \expandafter\pgf@sh@@temp\expandafter{\pgf@sh@@@temp}%
            \fi%
        \fi%
        {%
            \pgfsetcornersarced{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}%
            \pgfpathmoveto{\beforecalloutpointer}%
        }%
            {% <-
            \pgfsetcornersarced{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}% <-
            \pgfpathlineto{\calloutpointer}%
            }% <-
        {%
            \pgfsetcornersarced{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}%
            \pgfpathlineto{\aftercalloutpointer}%
        }%
        {%
            \pgftransformshift{\centerpoint}%
                \pgfpathlineto{\firstpoint}%
            \pgfpathlineto{\secondpoint}%
            \pgfpathlineto{\thirdpoint}%
                \pgfpathlineto{\fourthpoint}%
            {%
                \pgfsetcornersarced{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}%
                \pgfpathclose%
            }%
        }
    }%
    \anchorborder{%
        \pgfextract@process\externalpoint{}%
        \rectanglecalloutpoints%
        \pgfpointadd{\centerpoint}%
        {%
            \pgfpointborderrectangle{\pgfpointadd{\centerpoint}{\externalpoint}}%
            {\pgfqpoint{\xlength}{\ylength}}%
        }%
    }%
}%
\makeatother
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node [anchor=south west] at (0, 0) (cartoon) {\includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth,height=.15\textwidth]{example-image-a}};
        \node [anchor=north west,sharp rectangle callout,draw=black,
        callout absolute pointer=(cartoon.east), 
        rounded corners=3pt,text width=0.7\textwidth, 
        inner sep=2ex] at (.19\textwidth,.125\textwidth) {This is an example.};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

A perhaps "better" way of doing this is to modify the callout shape to include a switch for the sharp corner. This pays off if you add other switches, and do not want to define a new shape for each combination of switches. It can be "activated" e.g. with

```
\tikzset{/pgf/callout pointer sharp}
```

or by using this key in the node that you want to endow with a sharp corner at the callout pointer. The `\tikzset` command also allows you to install the sharp corners once and for all. (In principle the shape defined here could replace the current version as it is backwards compatible.)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.callouts}
\makeatletter
\newif\ifpgfcalloutpointersharp
\pgfkeys{/pgf/callout pointer sharp/.is if=pgfcalloutpointersharp,
/pgf/callout pointer sharp/.default=true,
/pgf/callout pointer sharp=false}
\pgfdeclareshape{rectangle callout}{%
    \savedmacro\rectanglecalloutpoints{%
        %
        \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@x{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep}}%
        \advance\pgf@x.5\wd\pgfnodeparttextbox%
        \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@xa{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/minimum width}}%
        \ifdim\pgf@x<.5\pgf@xa%
            \pgf@x.5\pgf@xa%
        \fi%
        \edef\xtemp{\the\pgf@x}%
        \pgfmathaddtolength\pgf@x{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep}}%
        %
        \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@y{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner ysep}}%
        \advance\pgf@y.5\ht\pgfnodeparttextbox%
        \advance\pgf@y.5\dp\pgfnodeparttextbox%
        \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@ya{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/minimum height}}%
        \ifdim\pgf@y<.5\pgf@ya%
            \pgf@y.5\pgf@ya%
        \fi%
        \edef\ytemp{\the\pgf@y}%
        \pgfmathaddtolength\pgf@y{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer ysep}}%
        %
        \edef\xlength{\the\pgf@x}%
        \edef\ylength{\the\pgf@y}%
        \addtosavedmacro\xlength%
        \addtosavedmacro\ylength%
        %
        \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\pointerwidth{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/callout pointer width}}%
        \addtosavedmacro\pointerwidth%
        %
        \pgfextract@process\centerpoint{%
            \pgf@x.5\wd\pgfnodeparttextbox%
            \pgf@y.5\ht\pgfnodeparttextbox%
            \advance\pgf@y-.5\dp\pgfnodeparttextbox%
        }%
        %
        % Process the relative callout pointer.
        %
        \ifpgf@lib@callout@absolutepointer%
        \else%
            \pgfextract@process\calloutpointer{%
                \pgfextract@process\borderpoint{%
                    \expandafter\pgfpointborderrectangle\expandafter{\pgf@lib@callout@relativepointer}%
                        {\pgfqpoint{\xtemp}{\ytemp}}%
                }%
                \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\pgfpointorigin}{\borderpoint}%
                \let\pointerangle\pgfmathresult%
                \expandafter\pgf@process\expandafter{\pgf@lib@callout@relativepointer}%
                \pgfmathveclen@{\pgfmath@tonumber{\pgf@x}}{\pgfmath@tonumber{\pgf@y}}%
                \edef\pointerradius{\pgfmathresult pt}%
                \pgfpointadd{\borderpoint}{\pgfqpointpolar{\pointerangle}{\pointerradius}}%
                \pgf@xa\pgf@x%
                \pgf@ya\pgf@y%
                \centerpoint%
                \advance\pgf@x\pgf@xa%
                \advance\pgf@y\pgf@ya%
            }%
            \pgf@lib@callouts@shortenpointer%
            \addtosavedmacro\calloutpointer%
            \pgf@lib@rectanglecallout@pointer%
            \addtosavedmacro\calloutpointeranchor%
            \addtosavedmacro\beforecalloutpointer%
            \addtosavedmacro\aftercalloutpointer%
            \addtosavedmacro\firstpoint%
            \addtosavedmacro\secondpoint%
            \addtosavedmacro\thirdpoint%
            \addtosavedmacro\fourthpoint%
        \fi%
    }%
    \savedanchor\centerpoint{%
        \pgf@x.5\wd\pgfnodeparttextbox%
        \pgf@y.5\ht\pgfnodeparttextbox%
        \advance\pgf@y-.5\dp\pgfnodeparttextbox%
    }%
    \savedanchor\basepoint{%
        \pgf@x.5\wd\pgfnodeparttextbox%
        \pgf@y0pt\relax%
    }%
    \savedanchor\midpoint{%
        \pgf@x.5\wd\pgfnodeparttextbox%
        \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@y{+.5em}%
    }%
    \anchor{center}{\centerpoint}%
    \anchor{mid}{\midpoint}%
    \anchor{mid east}{%
        \rectanglecalloutpoints%
        \midpoint%
        \advance\pgf@x\xlength\relax%
    }%
    \anchor{mid west}{%
        \rectanglecalloutpoints%
        \midpoint%
        \advance\pgf@x-\xlength\relax%
    }%
    \anchor{base}{\basepoint}%
    \anchor{base east}{%
        \rectanglecalloutpoints%
        \basepoint%
        \advance\pgf@x\xlength\relax%
    }%
    \anchor{base west}{%
        \rectanglecalloutpoints%
        \basepoint%
        \advance\pgf@x-\xlength\relax%
    }%
    \anchor{north}{%
        \rectanglecalloutpoints%
        \centerpoint%
        \advance\pgf@y\ylength\relax%
    }%
    \anchor{south}{%
        \rectanglecalloutpoints%
        \centerpoint%
        \advance\pgf@y-\ylength\relax%
    }%
    \anchor{east}{%
        \rectanglecalloutpoints%
        \centerpoint%
        \advance\pgf@x\xlength\relax%
    }%
    \anchor{west}{%
        \rectanglecalloutpoints%
        \centerpoint%
        \advance\pgf@x-\xlength\relax%
    }%
    \anchor{north east}{%
        \rectanglecalloutpoints%
        \centerpoint%
        \advance\pgf@x\xlength\relax%
        \advance\pgf@y\ylength\relax%
    }%
    \anchor{south west}{%
        \rectanglecalloutpoints%
        \centerpoint%
        \advance\pgf@x-\xlength\relax%
        \advance\pgf@y-\ylength\relax%
    }%
    \anchor{south east}{%
        \rectanglecalloutpoints%
        \centerpoint%
        \advance\pgf@x\xlength\relax%
        \advance\pgf@y-\ylength\relax%
    }%
    \anchor{north west}{%
        \rectanglecalloutpoints%
        \centerpoint%
        \advance\pgf@x-\xlength\relax%
        \advance\pgf@y\ylength\relax%
    }%
    \anchor{pointer}{%
        \rectanglecalloutpoints%
        \calloutpointeranchor%
    }%
    \backgroundpath{%
        \rectanglecalloutpoints%
        \pgf@x\xlength\relax%
        \pgf@y\ylength\relax%
        \pgfmathaddtolength\pgf@x{-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep}}%
        \pgfmathaddtolength\pgf@y{-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer ysep}}%
        \edef\xtemp{\the\pgf@x}%
        \edef\ytemp{\the\pgf@y}%
        %
        % The absolute pointer must be calculated here because the
        % anchor of the shape (which is calculated after the saved
        % macros and points) affects how the pointer joins the
        % main rectangle.
        %
        \ifpgf@lib@callout@absolutepointer%
            \pgfextract@process\calloutpointer{%
                \pgfpointanchor{pgf@lib@callout@pointer}{center}%
            }%
            \pgf@lib@callouts@shortenpointer%
            \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\pointerwidth{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/callout pointer width}}%
            \pgf@lib@rectanglecallout@pointer%
            %
            % \pgf@node@name = the shape name (from \pgfmultipartnode)
            %
            \ifx\pgf@node@name\pgfutil@empty%
            \else%
                %
                % Now hack an extra saved anchor \calloutpointeranchor,
                % with the new anchor for the callout pointer.
                %
                \edef\pgf@sh@@temp{\noexpand\expandafter\noexpand\pgfutil@g@addto@macro\noexpand\csname pgf@sh@np@\pgf@node@name\noexpand\endcsname}%
                \edef\pgf@sh@@@temp{%
                    \noexpand\def\noexpand\calloutpointeranchor{%
                        \noexpand\pgf@x\the\pgf@x%
                        \noexpand\pgf@y\the\pgf@y%
                    }%
                }%
                \expandafter\pgf@sh@@temp\expandafter{\pgf@sh@@@temp}%
            \fi%
        \fi%
        {%
            \pgfsetcornersarced{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}%
            \pgfpathmoveto{\beforecalloutpointer}%
        }%
        {% <-
            \ifpgfcalloutpointersharp% <-
                \pgfsetcornersarced{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}% <-
            \fi%
            \pgfpathlineto{\calloutpointer}%
        }% <-
        {%
            \pgfsetcornersarced{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}%
            \pgfpathlineto{\aftercalloutpointer}%
        }%
        {%
            \pgftransformshift{\centerpoint}%
                \pgfpathlineto{\firstpoint}%
            \pgfpathlineto{\secondpoint}%
            \pgfpathlineto{\thirdpoint}%
                \pgfpathlineto{\fourthpoint}%
            {%
                \pgfsetcornersarced{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}%
                \pgfpathclose%
            }%
        }
    }%
    \anchorborder{%
        \pgfextract@process\externalpoint{}%
        \rectanglecalloutpoints%
        \pgfpointadd{\centerpoint}%
        {%
            \pgfpointborderrectangle{\pgfpointadd{\centerpoint}{\externalpoint}}%
            {\pgfqpoint{\xlength}{\ylength}}%
        }%
    }%
}%
\makeatother
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node [anchor=south west] at (0, 0) (cartoon) {\includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth,height=.15\textwidth]{example-image-a}};
        \node [anchor=north west,
        /pgf/callout pointer sharp,%<- 
        rectangle callout,draw=black,
        callout absolute pointer=(cartoon.east), 
        rounded corners=3pt,text width=0.7\textwidth, 
        inner sep=2ex,
        ] at (.19\textwidth,.125\textwidth) {This is an example.};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your informative response. This is a more robust solution and not that hard to follow with clear description.

Comment: @ZHANGWuji Thanks for the kind words. I think that a cleaner possibility was to introduce a switch that allows you to make the corner sharp on demand, and not to define a new shape for a shape that is 99% coinciding with an already existing shape.

Comment: Sure, this is better to be patched as a k-v option to control shape of pointer, as uncontrollable varying pointer tip shape is really a  terrible feature.

Answer (score 2):

Workaround: draw the borders by yourself.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.callouts}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node [anchor=south west] at (0, 0) (cartoon) {\includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth,height=.15\textwidth]{example-image-a}};
        \node [anchor=north west,rectangle callout,
        %draw=black, <--- do not draw the node, you draw the borders afterwards
        callout absolute pointer=(cartoon.east),
        rounded corners=3pt,
        text width=0.7\textwidth, inner sep=2ex] (mynode) at (.19\textwidth,.125\textwidth) {This is an example.};
        \draw[rounded corners=3pt] (mynode.north west) -- (mynode.north east) 
        --
        (mynode.south east)
        --
        (mynode.south west)
        to[sharp corners]
        ([yshift=-.125cm]mynode.west) to[sharp corners]
        ([xshift=-.2cm]mynode.west) to[sharp corners]
        ([yshift=.125cm]mynode.west) -- cycle
        ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

For convenience, you could eventually create a `pic` (in case you have to use that node shape many time in your document):

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.callouts}
\tikzset{
  pics/myshape/.style={
    code={
      \node [anchor=north west,rectangle callout,
        callout absolute pointer=(cartoon.east),
        rounded corners=3pt,
        text width=0.7\textwidth, inner sep=2ex] (mynode) {#1};
      \draw[rounded corners=3pt] (mynode.north west) -- (mynode.north east) --
        (mynode.south east) -- (mynode.south west)
        to[sharp corners] ([yshift=-.125cm]mynode.west) 
        to[sharp corners] ([xshift=-.2cm]mynode.west) 
        to[sharp corners] ([yshift=.125cm]mynode.west) 
        -- cycle; 
    }
  }
}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [anchor=south west] at (0, 0) (cartoon) {\includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth,height=.15\textwidth]{example-image-a}};
    \pic at (.19\textwidth,.125\textwidth) {myshape=This is an example.};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The output is always:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This is helpful to me as in my case, I do not adjust the position of pointer in a large scale so that it is easy to wrap the code as a new command. By the way, I find this is also a workaround for [another qustion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150737/tikz-callout-positioning-start-of-pointer)  I have followed about controling the start point of callout box pointers.

Comment: @ZHANGWuji You're welcome! I'm glad my answer is useful. Thanks for the tip.